# Explain this 4D numpy array indexing intuitively

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
x = np.random.randn(4, 3, 3, 2)
print(x[1,1])

output:
[[ 1.68158825 -0.03701415]
[ 1.0907524  -1.94530359]
[ 0.25659178  0.00475093]]
```

I am python newbie. I can't really understand 4-D array index like above. What does x[1,1] mean?

For example, for vector

```
a = [[2][3][8][9]], a[0] = 2, a[3] = 9.
```

I get this but I don't know what x[1,1] refers to.

Please explain in detail. Thank you.

Comment: `x[1,1]` is a simple way to say : `x[1,1,:,:]`. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Divakar So x[1,1,:,:] means 1st and 2nd dimensions are to be printed and 3rd and 4th are to be ignored? Sorry if it is dumb question.

Comment: It's too early to accept an answer. There still might be interesting contribution from others.

Comment: @RPM it is rather like the opposite of your interpretation. `:` means take everything from the given dimension, while any singular index (i.e. 1) means take only what is at this precise index for the given dimension. As such any dimension with `:` will remain in the output while singular indies will result in that dimension being dropped from the output.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

A 2D array is a matrix : an array of arrays.

A 4D array is basically a matrix of matrices:

[image: matrix of matrices]

Specifying one index gives you an array of matrices:

```
>>> x[1]
array([[[-0.37387191, -0.19582887],
        [-2.88810217, -0.8249608 ],
        [-0.46763329,  1.18628611]],

       [[-1.52766397, -0.2922034 ],
        [ 0.27643125, -0.87816021],
        [-0.49936658,  0.84011388]],

       [[ 0.41885001,  0.16037164],
        [ 1.21510322,  0.01923682],
        [ 0.96039904, -0.22761806]]])
```

[image]

Specifying two indices gives you a matrix:

```
>>> x[1, 1]
array([[-1.52766397, -0.2922034 ],
       [ 0.27643125, -0.87816021],
       [-0.49936658,  0.84011388]])
```

[image]

Specifying three indices gives you an array:

```
>>> x[1, 1, 1]
array([ 0.27643125, -0.87816021])
```

[image]

Specifying four indices gives you a single element:

```
>>> x[1, 1, 1, 1]
-0.87816021212791107
```

[image]

`x[1,1]` gives you the small matrix that was saved in the 2nd column of the 2nd row of the large matrix.

Comment: Great answer. Simple and intuitive.

Comment: @eric Thanks for simplification. The output of x[1,1,1] gives an array, which looks like it is '2nd row' of matrix x[1,1]. What if I want '2nd column' instead? How to write this?

Comment: @RPM: `x[1, 1, :, 1]`

Comment: @EricDuminil perhaps you should add where the data will come from for each of your examples? What I mean is, that it is somewhat obvious that `x[1,1]` returns a matrix, but which one in your example is it?

Comment: @PeterE: Isn't "2nd column of the 2nd row of the large matrix." clear enough? What would you add?

Comment: @PeterE: No problem. Every answer is better with freehand circles.

Answer (score 7):

A 4d numpy array is an array nested 4 layers deep, so at the top level it would look like this:

```
[ # 1st level Array (Outer)
    [ # 2nd level Array
        [[1, 2], [3, 4]], # 3rd level arrays, containing 2 4th level arrays
        [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
    ], 
    [ # 2nd Level array
        [[9, 10], [11, 12]], 
        [[13, 14], [15, 16]]
    ]
]
```

`x[1,1]` expands to `x[1][1]`, Let's unpack this one expression at a time, the first expression `x[1]` selects the first element from the global array which is the following object from the earlier array:

```
[
    [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
    [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
]
```

The next expression now looks like this:

```
[
    [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
    [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
][1]
```

So evaluating that (selecting the first element in the array) gives us the following result:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

As you can see selecting an element in a 4d array gives us a 3d array, selecting an element from a 3d array gives a 2d array and selecting an element from a 2d array gives us a 1d array.